# MySQL regular expressions: How to replace a string using subexpressions?

Tags: mysql, regex

In my table I have strings like this:

```
Quisque scelerisque, odio ut ornare faucibus - IR:5443_XP
Maecenas eleifend felis in - IR:2077_XP
```

In the above string, I need to extract only the digits (5443, 2077) and convert the data to something like this:

```
Quisque scelerisque, odio ut ornare faucibus - Model ID = 5443
Maecenas eleifend felis in - Model ID = 2077
```

I have a large number of these in the database that I need to change. How can I do this in MySQL? I don't think MySQL's "REGEXP" function is powerful enough to do this. I think I need to use subexpression to store the digits and then retrieve them back to update the text into the second format.

I had a look at this: http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/ but I couldn't get it to run in my xampp environment.

Comment: What about [`UDF`](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp) ?

Comment: @hsz yes I had a look at UDF too but I'm not sure how to use it. Does it need to be installed? Can you tell me how to use it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this without a UDF.

```
SELECT
    `text` AS 'original_text',
    IF(`text` REGEXP '[[:<:]]IR:[0-9]+_XP$',
        CONCAT(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(`text`,CONCAT('IR:',SUBSTRING_INDEX(`text`,'IR:',-1)),1),
            'Model ID = ',
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`text`,'IR:',-1),'_',1
        )
     ),`text`) AS 'modified_text'
FROM `example_table`
```

having the table structure like:

```
CREATE TABLE `example_table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm not sure how fast or efficient this would be, though.

**EDIT:**

Sorry for the `SELECT` version. Here's the `UPDATE` one:

```
UPDATE `example_table`
SET `text` = CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`text`,CONCAT('IR:',SUBSTRING_INDEX(`text`,'IR:',-1)),1),
    'Model ID = ',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`text`,'IR:',-1),'_',1)
)
WHERE `text` REGEXP '[[:<:]]IR:[0-9]+_XP$';
```

Comment: If you want it to be case sensitive you might want to use the `BINARY()` in necessary places such as in the `WHERE` clause: `WHERE BINARY(\`text\`) REGEXP...`

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. That looks quite good. But what if multiple IR values appear within the same table cell, such as this being part of one cell: "Quisque scelerisque, odio ut ornare faucibus - IR:5443_XP
Maecenas eleifend felis in - IR:2077_XP"

Comment: @user1448031 You will need to use a UDF in that case. I wrote the answer based on your consistent examples.